# How can I implement this logic without null safety error?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm using getX to navigate to another page if the user account exists.

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Obx(
              () {
                if (accountExist.value) {
                  // return login button UI
                }else{
                  Get.to(ProductsPage());
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Im having the following error:

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

I want to navigate to the products page if the account exists. How can I implement this without the null error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply return the ProductsPage instead of navigating to it.

```
body: Obx(
        () {
           if (accountExist.value) {
              // return login button UI     
           } else {
              return ProductsPage();
           }
         },
      ),
```

Comment: Not working. Its returning the whole page inside the Column() widget I think, causing render error.

Comment: Yes, remove the column widget. You don't need a column here.

Comment: Yes this works. But, it is returning the widget inside the login page itself. That's why I want to navigate to the products page.

Comment: I guess you are using scaffold here and in the ProductsPage as well, which might give you 2 AppBars if you're using them. Remove the scaffold from this page, not the ProductsPage.

Comment: Exactly. I removed the app bar from the login page. But by doing, this the login page is destroyed?

Comment: It's not destroyed, return something useful in the body of accountExist condition and you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Added empty widget to else part.

```dart
body: Builder((context){
if(accountExist.value){
 Get.to(ProductsPage());
}
Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Obx(
              () {

                if (accountExist.value) {
                  // return login button UI
                }else{
                  return SizedBox();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I tried this, it is throwing a render error because its returning the widget after going to the page.

Comment: Try doing `Get.to(ProductsPage());` on InitState of statefull widget.

Comment: If not works try updated answer.

Comment: having same null error.

Comment: Have you tried this one `Try doing Get.to(ProductsPage()); on InitState of statefull widget.`

Comment: Im using stateless widget together with obx.

Comment: Try wrapping with builder. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **Get.to();** and use only widget in obx

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Obx(
              () {
                if (accountExist.value) {
                  // return login button UI
                }else{
                  ProductsPage();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Can you support your answer by modifying the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Obx(
              () {
                if (accountExist.value) {
              return Container();
                }else{
                  Get.to(ProductsPage());
                  return Container();
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```